# uint.Parse on a valid string throws System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing, uint

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DeviceIdMappings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Devices>
    <DeviceEntry>
      <Key>‭‭907579560</Key>
      <Value>SEMROUTER</Value>
    </DeviceEntry>
  </Devices>
</DeviceIdMappings>
```

CODE

```
string filename = @"C:\Users\Desktop\DeviceMapping.xml";
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            xmlDoc.Load(filename);
            var xml = XElement.Load(filename);
            Dictionary<uint, string> MasterDeviceMappings = (from x in xml.Descendants("DeviceEntry")
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        Key = x.Element("Key").Value,
                                        Value = x.Element("Value").Value,
                                    }
                        ).ToDictionary(q => uint.Parse(q.Key), q => q.Value);
```

Exexption
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
[image: Exception Image]

No idea whats wrong here. uint.Parse("907579560") works.

Comment: What's wrong is the input isn't valid.

Comment: Since you've got a screenshot of the debugger, why not see what `q.Key` contains...?

Comment: When I paste your XML into visual studio, I see two non-numeric characters prefixed to the value for `Key` `<Key>??907579560</Key>`. Some weird Unicode thing I expect. Just clean the XML file, and possibly also fix whatever generates it.

Comment: q.Key contains ‭‭907579560

Comment: @EdPlunkett wow, how did you see that i have opened the same file in visual studio!!

Comment: I copied from the web page and pasted it through `sed` to double the double quotes, so I could paste it into an @"" string in my C# file. It came out like that, with the question marks. Pasting it in directly from this page leaves those characters non-visible. So it was either my command line paste-to-stdout utility, sed, or my command line copy-to-clipboard-from-stdin utility. Cue twilight zone music.

Comment: Specifically, there are 2 null bytes after `<Key>` and before `907579560`

Comment: any tools i can see those chars or clean this up !!! VS does not showing those then !!

Comment: I pasted into HxD (Notepad++ also works if you select ANSI), but the easiest thing to do is going to be to delete that `<Key>...</Key>` line and re-type it by hand.

Comment: You can't mix XmlElement with XElement. Use XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();

Comment: @EdPlunkett and canton7 Yes some nonsense cahr are there i could change the encoding in notepad++ and see those. Thanks guys really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You have special non printable characters in the string. You can remove them by

```cs
uint.Parse(Regex.Replace(q.Key, @"\p{C}+", string.Empty))
```